# Using the sort function in python, having issues with it

Tags: python-3.x

```
howManyNames = (float(input("Enter how many student names do you want to enter? ")))
studentNames = []
ages = []
averageAge = 0
counter = 0

while (counter < int(howManyNames)):
    studentNames.append(input("Enter student names. "))
    ages.append(float(input("Enter that persons age. ")))
    counter += 1
    averageAge = sum(ages) / float(howManyNames)
print ("Your average age is ", averageAge, "!")

for age in ages:
   if age < int(averageAge):
      print ("Your age is below the average age.", age)
   else:
      print ("Your age is above the average age.", age)
```

I'm having issues trying to use the sort function I've tried print sort(ages) 
print ages.sort() but and etc but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` actually sorts the list in place. this would mean that if you did `print ages.sort()` you'd get `None`. Instead you can do, `ages.sort(); print ages;`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `print(sorted(iterable))` instead of `print(sort(iterable))` to sort an iterable.